# Command Playlist like music.

Tags: shell

So that idea has been in my head for a while, I often find myself launching a command and then wanting to launch another one after the one in progress finishes. 
The issue is that I have to monitor the ongoing command in order to launch the next one. 
There could be an 'up next' list which would run the commands one after the other, just like a music player. 
I don't think it exists but I wanted to make sure. 
I could very well develop such a thing if anyone is interested.

Comment: To be clear, you don't know that you want to run the second command at the time you start the first command, right?  Only after the first command is running do you decide what to run next.

Comment: Exactly, would't it be lovely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Hiradur said but maybe more suitable if the first command produces output (it might be annoying to type while the background process prints stuff):

1. Start the first command like always,
2. if you know what you want to run next press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the job
3. execute `fg; next_command` to continue with the current command in the foreground and execute `next_command` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You could just write your desired chain of commands down into a shell script or run them in a single line separated by a semicolon. This way they get executed in order and the next command starts after the previous command terminated.

`command1; command2; command3`

If you don't know beforehand which command to run next you can instead suspend the running process with `CTRL+Z`, make it process in the background with `bg` and start the next command like so: `wait %jobid; command2`. jobid can be determined with the `jobs` command. The jobid is in the [] brackets and the plus behind the brackets indicates the process which was running in foreground most recently.